# Google colab Glove_Python pip install not working

Tags: python, pip, google-colaboratory, stanford-nlp

I am using

```
! pip install glove_python
```

I'm getting this error message:

```
Collecting glove_python
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3e/79/7e7e548dd9dcb741935d031117f4bed133276c2a047aadad42f1552d1771/glove_python-0.1.0.tar.gz (263kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 266kB 16.9MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from glove_python) (1.19.5)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from glove_python) (1.4.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: glove-python
  Building wheel for glove-python (setup.py) ... error
  **ERROR: Failed building wheel for glove-python**
  Running setup.py clean for glove-python
  **ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for glove-python**
Failed to build glove-python
Installing collected packages: glove-python
    Running setup.py install for glove-python ... error
**ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1**: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-nypxp28t/glove-python/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-nypxp28t/glove-python/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-cnn32mbr/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

As suggested below I tried

```
! python -m pip install glove_python --verbose
```

Which outputs the following recurring error with different members:

```
has no member named ‘exc_{member}’; did you mean ‘curexc_value’?
```

And ends with:

```
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Running setup.py install for glove-python ... error
Cleaning up...
  Removing source in /tmp/pip-install-ru3hxbde/glove-python
Removed build tracker '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-ps3qzi71'
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ru3hxbde/glove-python/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ru3hxbde/glove-python/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-ywzvlm5m/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 153, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 455, in run
    use_user_site=options.use_user_site,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/req/__init__.py", line 62, in install_given_reqs
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 888, in install
    cwd=self.unpacked_source_directory,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/subprocess.py", line 275, in runner
    spinner=spinner,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/subprocess.py", line 242, in call_subprocess
    raise InstallationError(exc_msg)
pip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ru3hxbde/glove-python/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ru3hxbde/glove-python/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-ywzvlm5m/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Trying pip install glove-python-binary is successful but when I import it I get the following error:

```
    import glove-python-binary
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Try doing ```python -m pip install glove_python```

Comment: @GameDev it returns an invalid syntax error on Google Colab :/

Comment: @NandaPanda Command of comment from GameDev above should be done with `!` prefix. Also please try adding `--verbose` to pip command, what it outputs? It should give lots of details regarding reason of error.

Comment: @Arty thank you! I ran it as GameDev suggested but with --verbose and added the output to my question above :)

Comment: @NandaPanda After pip-installing `glove-python-binary` you have to `import glove` in your code. It often happens that module name inside `import` is different from module name in PIP, they're not obligatory same.

Comment: @Arty Ah! Oh man, thank you so much for walking me through this; its up and running now. You're a gentleman and a scholar Arty!

Comment: No answers in the question, please. I have rolled back/edited your question and removed the answer. Add the answer in the answer section only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like `glove_python` package is very old, last relese of it on PIP was in 2016. And it has only sources there, so should be compiled by C/C++ compiler, which is usually problematic everywhere (needs manual installing correct compiler and all dependencies).

Looks like updated version is `glove-python-binary` it dates to 2020. Try installing it through `! pip install glove-python-binary`.

According to [pypi site](https://pypi.org/project/glove-python-binary/) `glove-python-binary` needs Python of versions 3.6 or 3.7 or 3.8, smaller or bigger version of Python will not probably work.

When you have any problem or error in pip try adding `--verbose` to pip command line, this will print you a lot of details about reasons of pip failure.

Also as @GameDev [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66396100/google-colab-glove-python-pip-install-not-working/66397661#comment117381046_66396100) sometimes you have to also try running command `! python -m pip install PACKAGE` instead of `! pip install PACKAGE`, to install any Python pip PACKAGE, because first command uses exactly python that you use to run the script, while second may use `pip` from other Python installation, not from Python installation that is used to run actual script later.

Answer (score 3):

In the google-colab just write:

```
!pip install glove-python-binary
```

And for using, do this:

```
import glove
```

For example:

```
from glove import Glove
from glove import Corpus
```

This worked for me!